# Good historiography articles about Texas annexation?

Tags: historiography, annexation

I'm having a hard time finding a good historiography article about the Texas annexation on JSTOR. Could you help me find one? I'm not sure what to search for. ("Good" means that it lists common disagreements between historians on the topic.)